# C# Running ChromeDriver Selenium from Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

we use Azure Cloud service to host an MVC app which provides a UI for Admin functions across our clients data. Looking to host Selenium automation from the app.

When I bundle the ChromeDriver in the project, the following code works locally in the Azure emulator:

```
public SeleniumService(string username, string password, string path)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        var driverPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { path, "driver" });
        driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Timeout));
    }
```

However when I run from Azure, Selenium also needs the Chrome binary. I packaged the binary in the project directory, and if I specify the binary path in ChromeOptions...

```
public SeleniumService(string username, string password, string path)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        var driverPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { path, "driver" });

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
        {
            BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(new string[] { path, "binary" })
        };
        driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath,options);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Timeout));
    }
```

...I receive an error:

> unknown error: chrome failed to start (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

I am using ChromeDriver 2.19 and the version of Chrome.exe I bundled is 45.0.2454.93

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Anyone find a solution or workaround?

Comment: I think you need to include more than just chrome.exe in your deployment package. It has a bunch of files that go with it. If possible you should just run the Chrome installer.

Comment: Are you running your test cases on Azure hosted agent or on-prem? I use azure test plan for my automation with selenium. I can speak for myself I haven't use any chrome binary and it works fine for me on azure hosted agent. I am using "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" NuGet. and works fine for me. if you are using on prem make sure you have chrome installed on that machine